# Protractor-Flake is running the same script in all instances after retry instead of using only one instance

Tags: automated-tests, protractor

I have a project with Protractor, Protractor-Flake (To re-run failed tests, 3 times), Multicapabilities for parallelization in two instances. But when the first execution finishes, the failed spec is executed at the same time in two different instances, is it possible to have only one instance running on retry attempts, or at least if the two specs fail then to execute each spec in each instance. (On the first execution Test1 and Test 2 are running at the same time in different sessions) This is my config.json.

```
multiCapabilities:  [{
    browserName: 'chrome',
    shardTestFiles: true,
    maxSessions: 1,
    chromeOptions: {
      w3c: false
    },
    specs: ['../tests/Test1.spec.js']
  }, {
    browserName: 'chrome',
    shardTestFiles: true,
    maxSessions: 1,
    chromeOptions: {
      w3c: false
    },
    specs: ['../tests/Test2.spec.js']
  }],
```

And this is how the second attempt looks like:

```
Using multi to parse output
Re-running tests: test attempt 2
Re-running the following test files:
Test2.spec.js

[18:40:29] W/launcher - You have specified both capabilities and multiCapabilities. This will result in capabilities being ignored
[18:40:29] I/launcher - Running 2 instances of WebDriver
    [18:40:19] I/testLogger - [chrome #01] PID: 36072
    [chrome #01] Specs: Test2.spec.js
    [chrome #01]
    [chrome #01] [18:39:36] I/direct - Using ChromeDriver directly...
    [chrome #01] Started
    [chrome #01] Jasmine started
    
    [chrome #01] 3 specs, 1 failure
    [chrome #01] Finished in 41.496 seconds
    [chrome #01]

    
    [18:40:19] I/testLogger -
    
    [18:40:19] I/launcher - 1 instance(s) of WebDriver still running
    .[18:40:28] I/testLogger - 
    ------------------------------------
    
    [18:40:28] I/testLogger - [chrome #11] PID: 7760
    [chrome #11] Specs: Test2.spec.js
    [chrome #11]
    [chrome #11] [18:39:36] I/direct - Using ChromeDriver directly...
    [chrome #11] Started
    [chrome #11] Jasmine started
    [chrome #11] 3 specs, 0 failures
    [chrome #11] Finished in 49.188 seconds
    [chrome #11]
    [chrome #11] Executed 3 of 3 specs SUCCESS in 49 secs.
```

Answer (score 0):

You would have to look at how `protractor-flake` works internally to understand why this is happening. Without getting into too much detail, essentially what's happening is each running protractor instance gets restarted with the list of failed tests. Because You have two capabilities both of them are restarted with this list. You can see the code that causes this to happen [here](https://github.com/NickTomlin/protractor-flake/blob/1dc3d7c6bd40f8d434ebc4761faec59a100ed616/src/index.ts#L43).

That said, it doesn't make much sense to have two capabilities that are exactly the same. You have shardInstances set to true but are only running one test. As I'm sure you are aware, shardInstances is for parallel execution. Change the capabilities to something like this and it will solve your problem. It will still initially launch two specs, each with their own browser instance, and then the retry will only run the failed spec.

```
multiCapabilities:  [{
  browserName: 'chrome',
  shardTestFiles: true,
  maxInstances: 2,
  chromeOptions: {
    w3c: false
  },
  specs: [
    '../tests/Test1.spec.js',
    '../tests/Test2.spec.js'
  ]
}]
```